# Connect to SQL Server 2008 using Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I've downloaded SQL Server 2008 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1695), and I tried to connect it to Visual Studio 2013, but I get an error when I enter server name (`SQLSERVER2008`).

How can I know the correct server name?

Here is an image of the error:

[image]

Comment: Check your services and ensure the SQL Server service is installed started

Comment: which version of windows you're using?

Answer (score 0):

> Go to "Start" => "All Programs" => "Microsoft Sql Server"

and open "**Sql Server Configuration Manager**"
From there in left side pan, select "**SQL Server Services**". In right side pan, there will be something like "**SQL Server(instance name)**". what is in **parenthesis** is the name of your sql server. if you accept default setting during installation of sql server then most chances are that name of server is "**SQLEXPRESS**".

Further info is here

[How to check name of sql server](http://sqlserver-help.com/2011/06/19/help-whats-my-sql-server-name/)

Comment: when I click SQL Server Services I get this error: remote procedure call failed(0x800706be)

Comment: try "SQLExpress" in Visual studio 2013 for connecting visual studio with SQLServer. if it doesn't solve your problem then re-install sql server. there may be some error during installation

Comment: I still have sql server 2012 I installed it with visual studio 2013, should I un-installing SQL 2012 to solve the problem ?

Comment: you mean un-installing SQL 2012 , because I already installed it.